# How can i download any file from the firebase in react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am doing a simple project in react using my backend in firebase, so please, i need a sample code for downloading file from firebase created database. Looking forward for the precious response.

Comment: Do you mean download file from the firebase storage? I don't think you can upload/download "file" to database/firestore.

Comment: yeah exactly, i have seen like uploading the file firebase but i need the code to download from firebase storage!

Comment: Did you check the official doc? They have pretty good explanation there, https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files. If you are still unsure can give a sample though.

Comment: i have gone but still i need to sort out some issues, do you know? is there any idea or any example you got!!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here, can you give some context please?

Comment: i need a simple code in react to download a file from the stored database file in firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would get a reference to your storage (or directly to the file), then call getDownloadURL to get the URL, something similar to this.

```
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(); 
let downloadUrl = await storageRef.child('path/to/your/file').getDownloadURL();
```